# error with cross product

Tags: matlab, image-processing, cross-product

what's the error for here?

```
Img = imread('littlesquare.png');
Img = Img(:,:,1);
Img = double(Img);
[x,y] = size(Img);
I = ones(x,y);

 [R, L] = bwdist(Img);
 Rmag = bwdist(R);
 imshow(Rmag, []);
 B = cross(Img,Rmag);
 imshow(B)
```

I'm getting:

??? Error using ==> cross at 37
A and B must have at least one dimension of length 3.

even though imshow shows the expected image...

Comment: What are the sizes of `Img` and `Rmag`?

Comment: edit: imshow(B) doesn't show the image (obviously)

Comment: just did size(Rmag) and size(Img) and they are the same size

Comment: >> size(Img)

ans =

   136   177

>> size(Rmag)

ans =

   136   177

Comment: Neither of those has a dimension of length 3.  So you can't take their cross product, because it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

`bwdist` returns a grayscale image, that means `Rmag` won't have a dimension of length 3, so you can't calculate a cross-product on it.

Comment: thanks for your reply. how then do i take a distance transform of a 2d  image, in which the result can be used in a cross product? I am trying to superimpose a magnetic field from the image (current formed from image boundaries and trying to get distance of every pixel from the boundary) using biot savart's law B = I cross 1/R.

Comment: @brucezepplin: If I recall correctly, Biot-Savart works on vector fields, not scalar fields.

Comment: ok so how do I build a vector field from the image (in this case a square), and then take a distance transform of this so that the distance (or i guess displacement) is then a vector field too? then i can take the cross product of the image boundary and the displacement of each pixel from this boundary.

Comment: @brucezepplin: It depends on what your image represents.  I get the feeling you're just throwing code together without really understanding the maths you're trying to implement.  That's not productive.  I suggest you figure out what maths you need first.